# What is the best practice to store authentification config values on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, key-value-store

I have an app (java) deployed on heroku, my env are : Develop and Staging. My app is doing an authentification (jwt token) to an external api plateform.

So i'm creating a jwt token, using the standard approach : signin a private key (.pem) and creating a jwt token aprtre encoding (base 64) a payload. Everything works well.

But on my local, I'm storing all my variables on `application-contextual-values.properties` file

example :

```
secure.auth.iss=xxxxx
secure.auth.sub=yyy
secure.auth.iat=zzzz
secure.auth.pk=MIIE.... // this is my private key i use to sign on to create token
```

What is the best way to store this informations ? In my heroku vars config like this :

```
SECURE_AUTH_ISS : XXXX
SECURE_AUTH_SUB : YYYY
....
SECURE_AUTH_PK : MII.....
```

and for every env I'll add the right values ?

Both apps contain a postgres add-on.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is based on the [12 factor app](https://12factor.net/) principles, one of which is:

> [III. Config](https://12factor.net/config)
>
> Store config in the environment

For that matter, secrets are configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Your deployment could involve one WebDyno for development and one WebDyno for staging. In each environment you configure a [ConfigVars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) for each environment variable (ie SECURE_AUTH_ISS, SECURE_AUTH_SUB, etc..)

On each environment you then define the actual values you want to use.